# How much incurred costs of AWS EC2 traffic 1TB ? (AWS EC2 free-tier)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, traffic, amazon-lightsail

I can checked that AWS Lightsail can use 1TB traffic in month and will discharge $3.50 in month.
But I can't find information that use traffic and costs of AWS EC2 traffic in month ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Amazon Lightsail** includes Data Transfer traffic within the monthly cost.

The $3.50/month plan includes 1TB of Data Transfer. From [Amazon Lightsail FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/faq/):

> Both **data transfer in** and **data transfer out** of your instance count toward your data transfer allowance.

From [Amazon EC2 On-Demand Instance Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/):

- **Data Transfer In** is free
- The first 1GB of **Data Transfer Out** is free
- After that, **Data Transfer Out** is $0.09 per GB (with some cheaper options available)